# Conjecture about the elements of quotients of polynomial rings over commutative rings by principal ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity. For any polynomial $p(x) \in R[x]$ is there an element $a$ of $R[x]/ \langle p(x) \rangle$, $a \not \in R$ such that $a^n \in R$, where $n$ is the degree of $p(x)$? If not, does the same hold for some $n$, not necessarily the degree of $p(x)$?

Comment: This is confusing (or confused): when you say "$\;a\in R[x]/\langle p\rangle\;,\;\;a\notin R$..." , do you mean a coset in the quotient ring whose representative is *not* a polynomial of degree zero, or what?

Comment: And besides the above: since $\;a\in R[x]/(p(x))\;$ , then $\;a=f(x)+(p(x))\;,\;\;f(x)\in R[x]\;$ , and thus $\;a^n=f(x)^n+(p(x))\;$ . How can this last element be an element in $\;R\;$ ?? I think you must be trying to ask something but either I am misunderstanding something, or else you're messing things in your question and it makes almost no sense.

Comment: I'm treating $R$ as the subring of $R[x]/ \langle p(x) \rangle$ induced by the natural inclusion map $\iota : R \rightarrow R[x]/ \langle p(x) \rangle$ where $\iota(x) = x$. -- This is a common abuse of notation, but sorry that I wasn't clear at first.

Comment: What does it mean for $p(x)=x$ ? Then the quotient is isomorphic to $R$, which gives a contradiction to $a\not\in R$.

Comment: @Sintrastes What you call the "natural inclusion" may not even be injective and thus there is no embedding, e.g. if $\;R\;$ has non-trivial zero divisors. Not only that but either you meant $\;i(r)=r\;$ and **not** $\;i(x)=x\;$ as this last symbol is already used for the polynomials argument...

Comment: Add "$\deg(p)\geq1$", add "if $a$ does not belong to the image of $R$ in the quotient $R[x]/p$", change "for some $n$" to "for some nonzero natural number", and then your question makes perfectly sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not true. Take $p=2x-1$ in $\mathbf Z[x]$. Then $\mathbf Z[x]/p$ is the localization of $\mathbf Z$ by $2$, i.e., 
$$
\mathbf Z[\tfrac12]=\{\tfrac{m}{2^k}\mid m\in\mathbf Z, k\in\mathbf N\}.
$$
If $a\in\mathbf Z[\frac12]$ such that $a^n\in \mathbf Z$ for some nonzero natural number $n$, then $a$ is integral over $\mathbf Z$. Since $\mathbf Z$ is integrally closed, $a\in\mathbf Z$.

Of course, one can also show this directly without using the notion of integral elements. Indeed, if $(m/2^k)^n\in\mathbf Z$ for some nonzero integer $n$, then $m^n=2^{kn}\ell$ for some $\ell\in\mathbf Z$. It follows that $2^{kn}|m^n$, hence, $2^k|m$, which means that $m/2^k\in\mathbf Z$.